# ¿Como llamar el código de una interfaz gráfica (para no repetirlo varias veces), dentro de mi constructor en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

saludos.

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica básica en Python para captura y actualización de datos en un formulario simple.

**Tengo hecho ya mi método para capturar y agregar datos, el cual usa la interfaz del formulario que esta dentro de mi constructor.**

Ahora voy a desarrollar el método para actualizar dichos datos, y para ello, **voy a usar el mismo formulario, pero no quiero volver a copiar Y repetir todas esas lineas de código de mi interfaz**(es decir, mis Labels y mis Entry).

**Lo que quiero es saber como seria para crear una función con esa interfaz y llamarla luego desde cualquier método donde necesite usarla.**

Podrían por favor indicarme como hacerlo, así sea con un ejemplo básico cualquiera?

PD: Lo que quiero es re-usar la misma estructura de mi formulario ya sea para agregar o actualizar datos, sin tener que estar copiando y pegando las mismas lineas de código dentro de mis métodos.

Muchas gracias y quedo atento.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la tienes en la programación orientada a objetos y sus características (herencia, encapsulamiento, abstracción y modularidad).

Puedes usar herencia y composición según corresponda para reaprovechar clases y construir otras más complejas o con comportamineto ligeramente diferente. La práctica general es englobar las partes a reutilizar en una clase que derive de `tkinter.Frame` o derivados (como `ttk.LabelFrame`) que se suele usar como base.

Mejor un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class UserDataForm(ttk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(text="Datos del usuario")
        self.name = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.email = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.name)
        self.email_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.email)


        self.name_label = tk.Label(self, text="Nombre: ")
        self.email_label = tk.Label(self, text="Email de contacto:")

        self.submit_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Aceptar", command=self.submit)

        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="EW")
        self.email_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="EW")
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="EW")
        self.email_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="EW")
        self.submit_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")


    def submit(self):
        print(f"Nombre: {self.name.get()}")
        print(f"Email de contacto: {self.email.get()}")


class CompanyDataForm(UserDataForm):
    """
    Clase que hereda de UserDataForm y por tanto de partida tiene sus
    mismos objetos y métodos, por tanto mismos campos de formulario
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        # Modificamos un atributo heredado de la clase padre
        self.config(text="Datos de la Empresa")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        form = UserDataForm(self) # Composición
        form.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        tk.Button(
            self, text="Formulario Empresa", command=self.open_emp_form
            ).pack()

    def open_emp_form(self):
        sec_win =  tk.Toplevel(self)
        form = CompanyDataForm(sec_win) # Composición
        form.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```

Una de las ventajas de la POO y la representación de objetos mediante clases es precisamente la posibilidad de poder reutilizar cuantas veces quieras un código (generar instancias), permitiendo además componer nuevas clases a partir de otras bien por composición, bien por herencia, sin tener que repetir código.

Comment: Gracias amigo, voy a analizar esto y le comento. Bendiciones.